# Probability of IP address with all digits occuring exactly once

Tags: probability

I just realized that my IP address have all digits from $1$ to $9$ occurring exactly once, e.g. $91.745.86.23$ (though that is not my real address). **Just for fun, could anyone help me calculate the probability of that happening, assuming that all IP addresses have the same probability?** I could probably brute force it with a Python script, but I'm interested in how one would do it analytically.

It might be obvious, but remember that each field in an IP address range from $0$ to $255$.

Comment: I wonder if a brute-force approach would finish in reasonable time.

Comment: If each field ranges from 0 to 255, am I right in thinking your example cannot actually occur?

Comment: out of bruteforce it's 1 in 15856. Total cases: $256^4$. Good cases: 270720

Comment: Your IP address is not an IP address by definition.

Comment: Trefex: care to elaborate?

Comment: 91.745.86.23 is not a valid IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question can be reformulated to: If we 'concatenate' four numbers between 0 and 255, what's the chance the resulting number contains each of the digits 1 to 9 exactly once.

To answer this question, we need to count all possible permutations of the numbers 1 to 9. In order to get nine digits, the IP address has to either contain three two-digit numbers and one three-digit number, or two three-digit numbers, a two-digit number and a one-digit number. All three-digit numbers have to start with 1 or 2.

**Case 1**

There is one three-digit number. If it starts with 1, we can distribute the numbers 2 to 9 over the eight other positions, yielding $4\cdot8!$ options (times 4, since the three-digit number can be on any of the four positions). Counting the options starting with 2 is a bit harder. There are 24 three-digit numbers in $\{0,\ldots,255\}$ that can occur, starting with 2. This then leaves 6 digits that can be distributed in any possible way over the remaining 6 spots. As a result, there are $4\cdot24\cdot6!$ of these options.

**Case 2**

Since there are two three-digit numbers involved, we know one of these has to start with 1 and one of these has to start with 2. Omitting all three-digit numbers starting with 2 and containg 1 from the 24 mentioned in case 1, 14 remain (the lowest being 234). In each case, 4 out of 9 digits are known and the other 5 can be filled in any way we like. We now need to determine the number of orders for these blocks (the three-digit number starting with 1, the three-digit number starting with 2, the two-digit number and the 1-digit number), which is simply $4!$. In total this gives us $4!\cdot5!\cdot15$ possibilities.

As a final result, we get a chance of $$\frac{4\cdot8!+4\cdot24\cdot6!+4!\cdot5!\cdot14}{256^4}=\frac{270720}{256^4}.$$

Fortunately this agrees with the brute-force answer in the comments above.

Comment: Your solution looks quite short comparing to mine, did you take into account for example that in the IP $234.5.6.7$ we don't write down the left outmost zeros in $5.6.7$ as in the example that gave the OP ?

Comment: I took the first thing into account, yes. The reason for counting three-digit numbers beginning with 1 and 2 differently is that IP addresses are apparently composed of numbers $<256$. As a result, you don't just get the 1-1 correspondence you mention: you can, for instance have $189$, while $289$ can't occur.

Comment: oh you're right for the one and two, I didn't see this. But it seems that when you say "If it starts with 1, we can distribute the numbers 2 to 9 over the eight other positions, yielding 4⋅8! options (times 4, since the three-digit number can be on any of the four positions)", you assume that every other numbers have two digits...

Comment: Case 1 means there's just one three digit number (and hence three two-digit numbers), indeed.

Comment: what about 245.1.2.3 ? Actually it's included in your counting, because you can always choose other digits to fill the gap, but you don't know how many times you will count it I guess

Comment: 245.1.2.3 doesn't contain 9 digits, so it's not included. I'm not entirely sure what gap you're talking about. Since my answer obviously isn't clear, I'll edit it to include some more steps. That might help.

Comment: Ok, I just get it, this is my fault, I misred the OP's question. I thought it was "IP address such that every digit occurs at most once", this is why I couldn't understand your anwser...my bad

Comment: Misreading can happen to anyone indeed. Your problem sounds a lot harder to count, indeed. Glad it's clear now, though.

Comment: Thanks for this, I solved it numerically too and after fixing a bug it agrees with your conclusion. I'm a bit disappointed in myself that I did not realize how to solve it analytically, but at least I know how to now.

Answer (score 0):

### WARNING

I didn't read correctly your original question, so I actually tried to solve the problem "how many IPs where each digits occurs AT MOST once is there ?". So, it is not a anwser to your exact question (actually, it is more complex, because you need to take into account the cases where numbers have only 1 digit between two points, and so on)...But now I've written it, I post it anyway

I would first fix the number and the repartition of "invisible" zeros that occur in front position, or in other words the number of digits you will use in each of the fourth area separated by points. Let call $s=(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$ this state, with $0 \leq s_i \leq 2$ (if one of the 4th sub-IPs is zero, then it counts as one digit, and not as "nothing", since you have to wrote down this zero and it you can't use it in another place). So, for example, the IP address you gave 91.745.86.23 (well it's misleading because you used $745$ that is greater than $255$, but it doesn't matter for now) the corresponding configuration would be $(1,0,1,1)$.

From now on, since Ip's can be permuted, we can assume w.l.o.g that $s$ is in decreasing order up to a relabelling of $s$.

### case 1

One see that, each time a $s_i$ is $0$, you will have 3 digits in the corresponding area, and the first digit can't be zero (else $s_i=1$ actually, because you don't write 021.15.1.1 but 21.15.1.1). So you have only two choices for the most left digit, which are $1$ and $2$. So you can't have more than two $s_i$ that are null, else $1$ or $2$ will repeat. If you are in this case (only two $s_i$'s null), then the area corresponding to the $2$ will have two digits (right most remaining digits) between $0$ and $5$ to set (since you must be smaller than $255$), but $1$ and $2$ are already discarded by the two left most ones. So you are left with only four possibility ($0,3,4,5$) hence you must use these four digits and you have $4 \times 3 = 12$ ways to do it (number of couples with distinct elements in a set of cardinality 4). For every others digits, you must use the remaining $\{0,\ldots,9\}$ where you remove the elements you already picked, id est $1,2$ and two previous digits. You have at most six digits to fill (when $s_3=s_4=1$), so you can always do it, and this is just the same as finding an arrangement of $\{1,\ldots,6\}$ (10 possiblites minus 4 previous choices) of size $\Sigma = 2 + 3-s_3 + 3-s_4$, which is the total number of digits you can freely fill. So you have $6(6-1)\ldots(6-\Sigma+1)$ choices (still number of arrangements)

### case 1 - summary

Let's sum up a little, for this first case :

- you have $2$ choices for the $1$ and the $2$ : either your IP has the form "1XX.2XX.[..]" or "2XX.1XX.[..]".
- you have 12 choices for the repartition of the two digits corresponding to the three-digits area beginning with two
- you have $6(6-1)\ldots(6-\Sigma+1)$ choices for the remaining digits
- such a configuration has probability $p$ to happen, where $p = \frac{N}{256^4}$ and $N$ is the number of such kind of configurations, which correspond to the pick of positions of $s_1$ and $s_2$, 2 among 4, id est $6$, and then a couple of $1$s and $2$s for $(s_3,s_4)$, id est $2^2=4$ choices, so that $N=6 \times 4 = 24$

The only thing left is to categorize configurations with respect to their $\Sigma$, but you have very few cases. $\Sigma=4$ iff $s_3=s_4=1$, so one case. $\Sigma=5$ iff $(s_3,s_4)=(1,2)$ or $(2,1)$, so two cases. $\Sigma=6$ iff $s_3=s_4=2$, 1 case. This is not suprising, we found the binomial coefficients for $n=2$ which are $1-2-1$.

### case 2

Now, let's pick such a configuration where only $s_1=0$. Let $d$ be the left-most digit, $d \in \{1,2\}$. If $d=2$, you have to pick two different number between $0$ and $5$ for the two remaining digits of the left-most area (where there are $3$ digits, since it must be smaller than $255$) but excluding $2$ that is already taken by the left-most one, so you have $4 \times 3 = 12$ choices. Then, for the remaining digits, each time you make a pick, you can choose between $0$ and $9$ excluding the already choosen 3 left-most digits, ie you pick in a set of cardinal $10-3=7$. You have at most $6$ digits to choose (if $s_2=s_3=s_4=1$), so you can always do it, and this is just the same as finding an arrangement of $\{1,\ldots,7\}$ of size $\Sigma = 3-s_2 + 3-s_3 + 3-s_4$, which is the total number of digits in the remaining three right-most areas. You have $7 \times (7 -1) \times \ldots \times (7-\Sigma+1)$ choices

### case 2 - summary

For such a valid configuration, with $d=2$, let's sum up the number of possibilities :

- you have $12$ choices for the following two digits
- you have $7 \times (7 - 1) \times \ldots \times (7 - \Sigma+1) $ for the remaining ones
- such a configuration has probability $p$ to happen, where $p = \frac{N}{256^4}$ and $N$ is the number of such "valid" configurations, which correspond to the pick of the position of $s_1$ ($4$ choices) and then a 3-uple of $1$s and $2$s, id est $2^3=8$ choices, so that $N=4 \times 2^3 = 32$

One again, the only thing left is to categorize configurations with respect to their $\Sigma$. $\Sigma=3$ iff $s_2=s_3=s_4=1$, so one case. $\Sigma=6$ iff $s_2=s_3=s_4=2$, so also one case. $\Sigma=4$ iff only one $s_i$ is $2$, 3 cases (choose the position of the two, or do it by hand). $\Sigma=5$ iff only one $s_i$ is 1, which is also 3 cases (choose the position of the one). This is not suprising, we found the binomial coefficient for $n=3$ which are $1-3-3-1$.

### case 2 bis

When $d=1$, then you just have to pick the remaining $\Sigma' = 2 + 3-s_2 + 3-s_3 + 3-s_4 = 2 + \Sigma$ digits among $10-1=9$ possibilites, id est $9 \times (9 - 1) \times \ldots \times (9 - \Sigma+1)$

### case 2 bis - summary

For such a valid configuration, let's sum up the number of possibilities :

- you have $9 \times (9 - 1) \times \ldots \times (9 - \Sigma+1) $ for the remaining ones
- same p as previous case

Then for $\Sigma'$s repartition, it is the same case than previous but you just need to add $2$ to $\Sigma$.

Finally, I would say, if you call $A_i(n)=i(i-1)\ldots(i-n+1)= \frac{i!}{(i-n)!}$ the number of arrangement of length $n$ in a set of size $i$, then the total probability is

$$P=\frac{1}{256^4}( 4 \times 12 (A_9(5) + 3A_9(6) + 3A_9(7) + A_9(8)) + 4 \times 12(A_7(3) + 3A_7(4) + 3A_7(5) + A_7(6)) + 6 \times 2 \times 12(A_6(4) + 2A_6(5) + A_6(6)) )$$

Numerically, I found something like 1.259%

Comment: This looks like one heck of a job. Unfortunately, as you also have noticed, you are not answering my question. :-) Additionally, I think my question is more interesting; IP addresses like 1.2.5.64 or 2.3.45.1 are not very interesting, they are much too common.

Comment: Yes, actually there are a lot of small cases that are almost the same, so this is verbose but not that complex. Anyway even if it was fun to do, next time I'll read the question more carefully ^^

Answer (score -1):

I get 270 720 good cases....

Calculation:

First case
...,..,..,.. (plus permutation of groups)

1..,..,..,.. => 8! * 4 (4 = Perm of groups) = 161 280

2..,..,..,.. => 3 * 7! * 4 (second nr in three digit is 1,3 or 4) + 
3 * 6! * 4 (second nr in three digit is 5) = 69 120

Second case
1..,2..,..,. (plus perm of groups 4!)
=> 2 * 6! * 4! (1..,23., or 1..,24.,) + 2 * 5! * 4! (1..,25.,) = 40 320

Total: 270 720

Gives prob.

Comment: Hi Oscar. :-) Why is 4! = Perm of groups? If there is only one three-group, isn't the number of permutations 4 just like HSN says above?

Comment: Just realized my mistake! Changed...