# Find total size/cost of list of IP addresses which is created randomly

Tags: probability

I am creating a random IP addresses around 1 MILLION with the help of random function.
I want to know what total cost of my structure is or how big is my data structure? 
Repetition of prefix than NO COST otherwise ‘1’

```
   (0-255) .    (0-255) .   (0-255) .    (0-255)
1)       101        . 48.           1.         200
cost =    1.          1.            1.          1

2)        101        48.            2.         48
cost = Zero Cost    Zero Cost.      1.          1

3)        101.       29.            1.         200
cost = Zero Cost.     1.             1.         1
```

It might be obvious, but remember that each field in an IP address range from 0 to 255.

```
so on……..
I want to know the probability as well
Anybody guide me
```

Answer (score 0):

Although i am not from mathematics or statistics field but i hope [Probability of IP address with all digits occurring exactly once](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787865/probability-of-ip-address-with-all-digits-occuring-exactly-once?lq=1) will be of some help or may be this article about [generating random IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137340/could-a-truly-random-number-be-generated-using-pings-to-psuedo-randomly-selected)